# Unable to login in same address when hit the REST service using java

Tags: javascript, java, rest, session-cookies, cookie-httponly

I hit the rest URL

```
https://db2adminpc1:9443/rest/bpm/wle/v1/search/query?organization=byInstance&run=true&shared=false&filterByCurrentUser=true
```

using HttpURLConnection class and I get the SJON data in inputstream.

But in my requirement when I hit the URL it should store some kinda of token or cookie to authenticate the url when I open same in chrome browser.
You can find code below:

```
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(Data.getBytes());

    URL url = new URL(
            "https://db2adminpc1:9443/rest/bpm/wle/v1/search/query?organization=byInstance&run=true&shared=false&filterByCurrentUser=true");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    String encoding = new String(encodedBytes);// "cGNhZG1pbjpwY2FkbWlu";
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    connection.getRequestProperty("Set-Cookie");

    System.out.println("Session iD " + connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"));
    System.out.println("Session iD " + connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"));

    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        InputStream content = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            // System.out.println(line);
            sb.append(line);
        }
        content.close();

    } else {
        sb.append("\"Username And Password Does Not Match!!!\"");
    }

}
```

`Update I am able read LTPatoken2 but dont know how to put or store in localhost cookie and authenticate the URL`

Answer (score 0):

Because of `HttpURLConnection` not maintain the cookie,so you have to save the `Set-Cookie` header into a `String` instance while first visit the url,and then,for every next request,you should set request header named `Cookie` through call method `setRequestProperty`.Of course,you can use HttpClient Library,it can maintain cookie automaticly

Comment: I am able to get the cookie, Basically I calling rest service using localhost to the WebSphere.And I want it to store cookie into to my WebSphere URL.